# Better way to use cmake commands directly as custom command instead of wrapper scripts?

Tags: cmake

Currently I have like ~4 scripts that just wrap around some simple CMake commands like "FILE(COPY ...)" or "CONFIGURE_FILE(...)" so I can use them with the **-P flag** in custom commands like:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(  ${target}_TMP_RESOURCES ALL
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFILES_LIST="${${target}_RESOURCES}" -DDESTINATION="${BUILD_INTERMEDIATE_DIR}/${target}/bin/assets" -DEXCLUDE_EXT=".svn .git CVS .DS_Store" -P ${ROOT_DIR}/cmake/scripts/copyFiles.cmake
                    DEPENDS "${target}_TMP_BIN_DIR" 
                    COMMENT "Collecting resource files..." )
```

The **-E flag** looks like what I want, unfortunately it supports only very few platform commands according to the documentation.

So, is there a better way to use CMake commands in custom commands without running cmake in script mode and having to write these simple scripts?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, but it would certainly be useful. What could be done is generate the script on the fly using FILE(WRITE).

Comment: The FILE(WRITE) method is interesting, maybe it can be put into a macro so it does this job automatically and can even clean up later. At least I should be able to reduce the count of scripts necessary to 1. I will try to do that. Thank you for the suggestion.